# F# Types and Function signatures

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm new to F# and I'm trying a few thing to get my head around the language.

I have to two types almost identical (Coordinate and Vector). Because of this type inference cannot work properly and I have hard time to specify the correct type on each function.

It somehow undestand that's a Vector here:

```
type Coordinate = {X:int; Y:int}
type Vector = {X:int; Y:int}

let calculateVector (origin:Coordinate) (destination:Coordinate) = { X=destination.X-origin.X; Y= destination.Y-origin.Y;}
```

And here when I want a return type of Coordinate, I cannot find how to specify the return it for this function:

```
let calculateNextCoordinate (coordinate:Coordinate) direction = 
   match direction with
   | "N" -> { X=coordinate.X; Y=coordinate.Y-1 }
   | "NE" -> { X=coordinate.X+1; Y=coordinate.Y-1 }
   | "E" -> { X=coordinate.X+1; Y=coordinate.Y }
   | "SE" -> { X=coordinate.X+1; Y=coordinate.Y+1 }
   | "S" -> { X=coordinate.X; Y=coordinate.Y+1 }
   | "SW" -> { X=coordinate.X-1; Y=coordinate.Y+1 }
   | "W" -> { X=coordinate.X-1; Y=coordinate.Y }
   | "NW" -> { X=coordinate.X-1; Y=coordinate.Y-1 }
   | _ -> coordinate
```

I have this error on the default case: *This expression was expected to have 'Vector' but here has type 'Coordinate'*

i tired to have a look on this website for function signatures but could not something for my problem: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-signatures/

**Questions:**

How do you fix this error?

Is it because inference type take by default the last type declared that match the properties (in my example Vector)?

Bonus: Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation in F#?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since records are constructed using their member names:

```
{ X = 2; Y = 3}
```

you created a naming conflict between Vector and Coordinate. In F# the compiler always resolves to the latest definition in such cases and therefore, in your example, the compiler will interpret the record { X = ..., Y = ...} as a Vector.

There is a good article on [F# records on fsharpforfunandprofit.com](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/records/#naming-conflicts), that explains how to handle this easily, which I suggest you read for a good explanation.

But in short, you can prefix either member of the record instance with the record type:

```
{ Coordinate.X = 2; Y = 3 }  // Creates a Coordinate
{ X = 2; Coordinate.Y = 3 }  // Creates a Coordinate
```

and

```
{ Vector.X = 2; Y = 3 } // creates a vector
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for, and the links is really good.